# URL shortener without traffic check

Tags: url-shortening

I'm looking for a url shortener.

The following things are important:

- Pay per click (high payout for one click)
- No traffic checks, you should also get money when the visitor of the short url uses a proxy or VPN and also when the visitor is only 3 seconds or less on the website (this is the most important for me!)
- Payment via Bitcoin or PayPal
- URLs should be marked safe to visit in Chrome and Firefox (no red alert window) -> also very important!
- Low payout limit if possible
- No need to enter my address when registering

Do you have any ideas?